# Regular Expression issue, deleting whole lines

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying for the last couple of hours to create a regular expression that deletes lines of text that start with particular wordage after selecting out a rating.

Below is what I'm trying to delete. I'm also trying to pull the Rating out of the paragraph (it's pass or fail).

```
Review Master: text here 
1111111111 text here 
Rating: Fail text here 
Review Master Page text here
```

I am trying to delete all lines that start with the following.
I have

```
^Review Master:
^[0-9]{10}
^Rating:
^Review Master Page
```

Again, I am struggling with the replacement(deleting) and finding only the rating.

Comment: Which tool/language are you using for this?

Comment: You are trying to get only Pass or Fail out of a file containing a lot of those lines?

Comment: I am using Java, Yes Out of those 4 lines im trying to get the pass/fail out then delete them out of the text file

Comment: Reading and writting (i.e. rewritting, what you call deleting) are two different actions.  I'd write a regexp for what you want and then rewrite the file with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find those exact lines in your file then this will work:

```
Review Master:\n\\d++\nRating:\\s*+(\\w++)\nReview Master Page"
```

Here is an example using your input as a test string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String in = "Review Master:\n"
            + "1111111111\n"
            + "Rating: Fail\n"
            + "Review Master Page";
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(""
            + "Review Master:\n"
            + "\\d++\n"
            + "Rating:\\s*+(\\w++)\n"
            + "Review Master Page").matcher(in);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Fail
```

If you want to delete those lines then your need to replace the pattern in the file which your have as a `String`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String in = "Some other text\n"
            + "Review Master:\n"
            + "1111111111\n"
            + "Rating: Fail\n"
            + "Review Master Page\n"
            + "Some final text";
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(""
            + "\n?"
            + "Review Master:\n"
            + "\\d++\n"
            + "Rating:\\s*+(\\w++)\n"
            + "Review Master Page").matcher(in);
    final StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(output, "");
    }
    m.appendTail(output);
    System.out.println("Result: \"" + output.toString() + "\"");
}
```

Output:

```
Fail
Result: "Some other text
Some final text"
```

i.e. we use the `Matcher` to yank the pass/fail from the input and also build the output replacing the block of text matched with nothing.

You have not made clear which parts of the patterns are variable.

Comment: I have a large String field that i get from reading in a PDF, inside of that PDF are some of the lines I have provided. I am trying to parse the String(pdf) and remove the lines above but at the same time i need to pull out the Pass or Fail value. I hope this clarifies a little bit. The lines I have listed are the beginning of the new line that I need to delete.

Comment: The second code snipped should work - it will find the occurrences in the input string and for each encounter it will give your the `Pass|Fail` and also strip out the entire section.

Comment: So should I just set the String in equal to my PDF text? I tried that and I am not getting any matches.

Comment: I am not, I'm running fedora.

Comment: In that case check your actual string for spaces in the input - for example trailing spaces at the end of lines. Try adding `\\s*+` before the line breaks.

Comment: Still no results found. Im still getting the following for each page that is in the string.
Review Master: Review File No.
1111111111
Rating: Fail
Review Master Page 3 of 1000

Comment: That does not look much like the string in the example.

Comment: The example says that their is text after each "Rating: Fail text here " sorry if it was not clear. But the text after each beginning changes.

Comment: Is it still possible to do?

Comment: Please provide some examples. Regex is a pattern matching language. One needs a pattern to match it...

Comment: Each one of the lines is in the beginning, A line with start with Rating: or start with Review Master: or start with 10 numbers. After the beginning of the line everything changes. But i wanted to delete the entire line(s) after I pull out the pass or fail message.

Comment: Instead of a `\s*+` add a `.*?` before the linebreak. That should do it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44438/discussion-between-user1857654-and-boris-the-spider)